# How to solve this sql query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query to fetch rows from wpr_subscribers provided that the conditions in the query.

```
SELECT subscribers.* FROM wpr_subscribers subscribers, wpr_followup_subscriptions subscriptions WHERE 
            subscribers.id=subscriptions.sid AND
            subscribers.active=1 AND
            subscribers.confirmed=1 AND
            subscriptions.type='autoresponder' AND
            subscriptions.eid=$autoresponder_id AND 
            subscriptions.sequence = -2 OR
            CEIL((subscriptions.last_date-subscriptions.doc)/86400) >= $message_index
```

The query returns two of every row. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Please post the schema for the tables. Thanks!

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the query. Check that the duplicate rows aren't in the database, and post some PHP code.

Comment: you sure you don't need brackets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT subscribers.* FROM wpr_subscribers subscribers, wpr_followup_subscriptions
subscriptions WHERE 
        subscribers.id=subscriptions.sid AND
        subscribers.active=1 AND
        subscribers.confirmed=1 AND
        subscriptions.type='autoresponder' AND
        subscriptions.eid=$autoresponder_id AND 
        subscriptions.sequence = -2 OR
        CEIL((subscriptions.last_date-subscriptions.doc)/86400) >= $message_index
```

DISTINCT keyword would help you in returning only the unique(distinct) rows in the table. Are you sure on the logic of AND and OR in the query and the unique data that you will now receive is indeed correct. Just for the info, AND operator has precedence over OR however you can override that by using parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably your `OR` statement

```
        subscriptions.sequence = -2 OR
        CEIL((subscriptions.last_date-subscriptions.doc)/86400) >= $message_index
```

You should enclose this in parenthesis for whatever the scope of the `OR` is